# What is wrong with my code?

Tags: java, while-loop

// It keeps popping up with this error when I try to compile it that says that it reached the end of the file while parsing, leading me to believe that I have a problem with my '{}' brackets. Please Help!!!

// Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;

class GameOfNim

{ public static void main(String [] args)

    { Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    int marbles, player, difficulty, pick;

    marbles = (int)(Math.random()*90+10);

    player = (int)(Math.random()+0.5);

    difficulty = (int)(Math.random()+0.5);


  if(difficulty == 0)

  System.out.println("The Computer is now in Beast Mode!");

  else if(difficulty == 1)
  System.out.println("The Computer is now in easy mode.");

  System.out.println("The pile of marbles has: " + marbles + "total marbles. Game On!");

  while(marbles>0)
  { if(player==0)//person
  {System.out.print("Pick some marbles");
  pick = in.nextInt();}
  if (pick >= 1 && pick <= marbles/2){
  marbles = marbles - pick;
  System.out.println(marbles+"left");}

else if(pick < 1 || pick > marbles/2 && pile > 1){
    System.out.println("Error: Illegal Move.");
    player = 0;
    continue;}

else {
     marbles = marbles - pick;
     System.out.println(marbles + "left.");
     }}


   if(player == 1 && difficulty ==1)
   {
System.out.println("Computer's turn to pick");
pick = (int)(Math.random()*marbles/2+1);
marbles = marbles - pick;
System.out.println("computer picks: " + pick + "marbles." + "There are: " + marbles + " marbles left.");}

  else if(player == 1 && difficulty == 0)
  {
System.out.println("Computer's turn to pick");
if(marbles > 63)
    {pick = marbles - 63;
    marbles = marbles - pick;}
else if(pile > 31)
    {pick = marbles - 32;
    marbles = marbles - pick;}
else if(pile > 15)
    {pick = marbles - 15;
    marbles = marbles - pick;}
else if(pile > 7)
    {pick = marbles - 7;
    marbles = marbles - pick;}
else if(pile > 3)
    {pick = marbles - 3;
    marbles = marbles - pick;}

else{
pick =  (int)(Math.random()*marbles/2+1);
marbles = marbles - pick;
System.out.println("Computer picks: " + pick + "marbles." + "There are: " + marbles + " marbles left.");
 }
   {if(player==0)
     player=1;
   else player=0;
 }
   {if(player==0)
      System.out.println("Computer: 'I give up! You win!");
   else
      System.out.println("Computer: '...You are pathetic...'");
  }}
```

//Note: By debugging the code in chunks. It seems to be the problem may be in my While Loop. but I really don't know.

Comment: Crikey, get your code indented properly

Comment: @hd1 I was going to say that it is the main problem!

Comment: And often, there is a tool in most IDE that formats the code for you.

Comment: sorry this stack overflow didn't let me paste it in correctly from textPad and I am a beginner at coding if you can't tell.

Comment: I am speculating that you forgot to close the curly brace of the class.

Comment: Ok, I pressed reformat. Is this any better?

Comment: Where is pile declared?

Comment: Way better, but Jouwee already found the solution.

Answer (score 3):

First, your should indent your code properly. You should read a little bit about indentation conventions for Java. Here's an example of a correct indented code:

```
class GameOfNim {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        [...]
        if (difficulty == 0) {
            System.out.println("The Computer is now in Beast Mode!");
        } else if (difficulty == 1) {
            System.out.println("The Computer is now in easy mode.");
        }
    }
}
```

After fixing the indentation of your code, I have easily found that you are missing two closing brackets at the end of the file, one for your main method and one for your class.

Comment: it looks like that in textpad but not when I copy paste it. I tried closing it with another bracket, but same issue

Answer (score 2):

Buddy. You should really start by using a coding convention. A clause should either be:

```
void function(){
}
```

OR

```
void function()
{
}
```

And same goes for if, while loops and classes. Pick a coding standard and stick to it :)
As for your problem, you left out the closing bracket '}'  for closing the class.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you're missing two '}' characters, After copy/pasting your code into an IDE I noticed that there were complains about things not lining up. You missed two end brackets.

Also, upon further inspection, it looks like 'pile' never gets declared or initialized to any value.

Answer (score 0):

```
private String name;
private String email;
private int number;

public String getname(){
    return name;
}

public void setname(String name){
    this.name= name;
}

public String getemail(){
    return email;
 }
   
 public void setemail(String name){
     this.email= email;
}

public String getnumber()}
    return number;
    }
        
  public  staticvoid setnumber(String number){
    this.number= number;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     NameEmailnumber person= new NameEmailnumber();
     
     person.setname("Tumelo Monese");
     person.setemail("Monesetumelo03@gmail.com");
     person.setnumber("0676613198");


        System.out.println(" I am "+ person.getname());
        System.out.println( "my email is "+ person.getemail())
        System.out.println( " my phone number is "+person.getnumber())

}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35759263)

Answer (score -1):

you shoud try indented properly .
you can try to change

```
  {if(player==0)
     player=1;
   else player=0;
 }
   {if(player==0)
      System.out.println("Computer: 'I give up! You win!");
   else
      System.out.println("Computer: '...You are pathetic...'");
  }}  `enter code here`
```

with :

```
  if(player==0)
      player=1;
  else player=0;

  if(player==0)
      System.out.println("Computer: 'I give up! You win!");
  else
      System.out.println("Computer: '...You are pathetic...'");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not indented properly.